# Java-Supporting Plugins on my Java Server

Tags: java, events, plugins

Basically what I'm searching trying to figure out is how would I go with adding plugins to my Java server, like Bukkit and Minecraft do.

I was thinking of the following way:

Server.registerEvents(Class, Class to listen to), in other words something like this: Server.registerEvents(this, Player.class) and it would register it on the Server then to be settled as a static value on the Player class, but after that I don't know how to **trigger** that event, how would I go with such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for discovering plugins on the classpath

Comment: @Debels - glad i could help. its traditional to mark the correct answer ;-)

Comment: I know, just that at that moment I had to wait 3 more minutes :P